# Como criar um algoritmo que rastreie automaticamente certas paginas de um site?

Tags: algoritmo

Eu tenho uma plataforma onde as pessoas podem colocar comentários escrever opiniões e eu neste momento preciso de criar um algoritmo em que me rastreie essas mesma zonas do site caso alguém escreva um comentários menos impróprio o mesmo o apague do sistema automaticamente sem que eu esteja sem a deitar um olho no que as pessoas escrevem.

Gostaria de saber a melhor forma de fazer e sugestões de como o fazer.

Answer (score 3):

Não creio que rastrear a página em busca de comentários impróprios seja a melhor opção.

O que você pode implementar é um algorítimo que crie uma fila de aprovação dos comentários, obrigando que todos os comentários sejam aprovados pro algum moderador, assim como ocorre do [Wordpress](https://br.wordpress.org/).

Outra sugestão pode ser não permitir que alguns comentários sejam postados a partir de uma lista de palavras proibidas, barrando assim na hora que o usuário tentar incluir o comentário.
Você pode também combinar essa lista de palavras proibidas com a fila de aprovação para pré-aprovar os comentários que não possua essas palavras.

Answer (score 3):

Esta acção deverá ser feita **antes** da inserção da mensagem na base de dados, dessa maneira você não irá gastar recursos a percorrer uma página de X em X tempo.

pseudo-code:

```
if (coisa_inserida.contains('asneira'))
    nao_inserir_em_base_de_dados;
    mostrar_erro('asneiras nao sao permitidas');
}
else {
    inserir_em_base_de_dados(coisa_inserida);
    mostrar_sucesso('yay! comentario inserido!');
}
```

---

Pode, no entanto, fazer um sistema de *approval* - como o @gmsantos referio.